# Best way to tell a user they've been signed out due to inactivity in using FormsAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, session-timeout, message-passing

I'm working in Asp.NET MVC, and am trying to display a message to the user on the login page to inform them they've been logged out. I've got a Client side timer event which essentially fires a request that kills the Forms Authentication and Abandons the session, then forces a page reload which fires the FormsAuthentication redirect to the login page.

It's working pretty well overall, but I'm wondering how I can display a message to the user on the login page to say why it is they've suddenly been redirected. I was storing a flag in TempData, but now that I'm needing to clear Session as well that's not being retained.

I'm currently just loking for a returnUrl in the querystring which is ok but not great - is there a better way to detect to pass a message through that the user has been logged out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After you sign-out and session abandon you can insert yours message into tempdata and redirect to login action.

Comment: No idea why you would do this, but another option would be to display an alert/confirm in the current page as part of the script before your fire the request